# Fade in element when html5 video finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I fade in the element with class `play-pause` when the html5 video element with class `slider-video` finishes playing?

```
$('.slider-video').parent().click(function () {
  if($(this).children(".slider-video").get(0).paused){        
    $(this).children(".slider-video").get(0).play();   
    $(this).children(".play-pause").fadeOut();
  }else{       
    $(this).children(".slider-video").get(0).pause();
    $(this).children(".play-pause").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: There is a `videoElement.onended` Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Vanilla JS solution**:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slider-video').addEventListener('ended', function () { 
    /*do something*/ 
},false);
```

**Jquery solution**:

```
$(".slider-video").on("ended", function() {
  /*do something*/
});
```